# Botframework How to change table storage connection string in startup based on incomming request

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework, azure-bot-service, state-management

I'm using BotFramework version(v4) integrated with LUIS. In **ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)** method in **startup.cs** file I'm assigning storage and LUIS in the middleware.Below is the sample code.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton(configuration);

    services.AddBot<ChoiceBot>(options =>
    {    
        options.CredentialProvider = new ConfigurationCredentialProvider(configuration);
        var (luisModelId, luisSubscriptionKey, luisUri) = GetLuisConfiguration(configuration, "TestBot_Dispatch");//
        var luisModel = new LuisModel(luisModelId, luisSubscriptionKey, luisUri);
        var luisOptions = new LuisRequest { Verbose = true };
        options.Middleware.Add(new LuisRecognizerMiddleware(luisModel, luisOptions: luisOptions));

        //azure storage emulater
        //options.Middleware.Add(new ConversationState<Dictionary<string, object>>(new AzureTableStorage("UseDevelopmentStorage=true", "conversationstatetable")));

        IStorage dataStore = new AzureTableStorage("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=chxxxxxx;AccountKey=xxxxxxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net", "TableName");

        options.Middleware.Add(new ConversationState<Dictionary<string,object>>(new MemoryStorage()));
        options.Middleware.Add(new UserState<UserStateStorage>(dataStore));
    }
}
```

My bot will be getting requests from users of different roles such as (admin,sales,etc..).**I want to change the table storage connection-string passed to middleware based on the role extracted from the incoming request**. I will get user role by querying DB from the user-name which is extracted from the current TurnContext object of an incoming request. I'm able to do this in **OnTurn** method, but as these are already declared in middleware I wanted to change them while initializing in the middleware itself.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET Core, `Startup` logic is only executed once at, er, startup.

If I understand you correctly, what you need to be able to do is: at runtime, switch between multiple storage providers that, in your case, are differentiated by their underlying connection string.

There is nothing "in the box" that enables this scenario for you, but *it is possible* if use the correct extension points and write the correct plumbing for yourself. Specifically you can provide a customized abstraction at the `IStatePropertyAccessor<T>` layer and your upstream code would continue to work at that level abstraction and be none-the-wiser.

[Here's an implementation I've started that includes something I'm calling the `ConditionalStatePropertyAccessor`](https://github.com/drub0y/HackedBrain.BotBuilder.State/blob/master/Implementation/Conditional/ConditionalStatePropertyAccessor.cs). It allows you to create a sort of composite `IStatePropertyAccessor<T>` that is configured with both a default/fallback instance as well as *N* other instances that are supplied with a selector function that allows them to look at the incoming `ITurnContext` and, based on some details from any part of the turn, indicate that that's the instance that should be used for the scope of the turn. [Take a look at the tests and you can see how I configure a sample that chooses an implementation based on the `ChannelId` for example.](https://github.com/drub0y/HackedBrain.BotBuilder.State/blob/478f3f59d57115685662bde3e1d252e2e1a1e7fc/Tests/Conditional/ConsiditionalStatePropertyAccessorTests.cs#L15-L43)

I am a little busy at the moment and can't ship this right now, but I intend to package it up and ship it eventually. However, if you think it would be helpful, please feel free to just copy the code for your own use.